How do I use Bootstrap 5.3.3 css and have the buttons back to their original colours with glyphicons?
I have been using Dropzone.js for a few years and have an app that has been working well. There are three buttons that are used.
<span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
    <span>Browse files...</span>
</span>

<button class="btn btn-primary start">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></i>
    <span>Start</span>
</button>

<button data-dz-remove class="btn btn-danger delete">
   <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
   <span>Remove</span>
</button>

I have been using bootstrap@3.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css from cdn.jsdelivr.net and as I said it works well. The buttons look like this:

I would now like to add a modal but it doesn't work with Bootstrap 3.1.1
If I use bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css from cdn.jsdelivr.net the buttons look like this:

The modal works but the button colour is slightly different and I have lost the glyphicons.
I would like to use the latest version possible of the Bootstrap css.
If I use bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css from cdn.jsdelivr.net the buttons look like this:

The modal works but again the button colours are slightly different and the glyphicons have disappeared. Also the Remove button only has an outline and no fill.
How do I use Bootstrap 5.3.3 css and have the buttons back to their original colours with glyphicons?
Ultimately I would like to use my own custom coloured buttons with either glyphicons or font-awesome icons. Is this possible?

i dont believe bootstrap supports glyph icons anymor but they do support feather fontawesome and octicons there have also indeed been a change in their color set which you might not like you might override thier current scss/_variables.scss to import the old _variable.scss so it wil access the old colors instead of the new ones. i do advise this is not a pretty way to do it but it might resolve your issue

If you want to change the color of the button to the original color is to change the span html element to a button html element. Then take the  html elements and put them inside within the button element. For the first button that one should look like this <button class="btn btn-success" type="button" value="Input"

please close your  tag, and  may want to use code formatting in your message.
